# Date-Time-Range directive field is not showing any values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, angular-directive

I have created an Date Time Range Directive in AngularJS. I am using **[dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)** plugin for getting the Date Time Range Calendar. The directive is working fine as well as the model value is getting changed but the view is not updating.

```
      element.data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(val.start); 
      element.data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(val.end);
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this.

My Directive which I have  created is given below

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nQeI8v2YGii8rZtIAW1R?p=preview)**

**script**

```
app.directive('dateTimePicker', function($parse, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

      var html = "<form>" +
        "<div class='form-group'>" +
        "<div class='input-group'>" +
        "<span class='input-group-addon'>" +
        "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "<input type='text' name='reservation' id='reservationtime' class='form-control' value=''/>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</form>";

      var newElem = $(html); 

      element.replaceWith(newElem); 

      return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        element.on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) 
        {
          var date = {};

          date.start = picker.startDate;
          date.end = picker.endDate;
          scope.$apply(function (scope) {
              modelAccessor.assign(scope, date); 
           });
        });  

        element.daterangepicker({
          timePicker: true,
          timePickerIncrement: 30,
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
        });

        scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function(val) 
        {
          console.log(val);
          if(!_.isUndefined(val))
          {
            element.data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(val.start); 
            element.data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(val.end); 
          }
        });  

      };

    }
  };
});
```

**html**

```
  <date-time-picker ng-model="dateTimeRange"></date-time-picker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updateInputText: function() {
            if (this.element.is('input') && !this.singleDatePicker) {
                this.element.val(this.startDate.format(this.format) + this.separator + this.endDate.format(this.format));
            } else if (this.element.is('input')) {
                this.element.val(this.endDate.format(this.format));
            }
        }
```

This code snippet from daterangepicker.js is responsible for updating the view.

In the dateTimePicker directive, the root element of the template i.e, form element is converted to daterange widget using element.daterangepicker where as input element inside the template should be converted.

`element.find('input').daterangepicker({})` worked for me.

Comment: one more help... can you please tell me why the date icon is not coming in that text field

Comment: check this [demo](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/) there the icon is coming correctly

Comment: Calendar icon is loaded from font-awesome.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
include this in your html file.

Comment: hey one issue is there, say when I select from and to date as `02/02/2015 12:00 AM - 02/03/2015 11:59 PM`, the model value is showing  `{"start":"2015-02-02T06:00:00.000Z","end":"2015-02-04T05:59:59.000Z"} `. Instead of `2015-02-03` it is showing `2015-02-04` for end date

Comment: Problem is with the serialization of json object having dates in it. 
While serializing it considered a different timezone.
`JSON.stringify({"date": new Date()})
"{"date":"2015-02-23T09:12:54.023Z"}"`
`new Date()
Mon Feb 23 2015 14:43:24 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: so what we have to do inorder to overcome this issue

Comment: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/11/how-to-serialize-date-and-datetime-without-losing-information/

Comment: I have tried out with `DateTime.parse` in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tCoptcTHl7HmOqKabNy?p=preview) , but still not getting worked out

Comment: `date.start = picker.startDate._d.toUTCString();
date.end = picker.endDate._d.toUTCString();`
Save the values as UTCString and while re using it use as `new Date(date.start)`